# How to set namespace correct in PHP?

Tags: php

I have load file `index.php` in server in directory `public_html`.
In this file I set namespace and use like as:

```
namespace public_html;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

set_time_limit(0);

use public_html\Helper\Curl\CurlHeaders;
use public_html\Helper\Curl\Curl as Curl;
use public_html\Helper\Pdo\FacadeQuery as Db;
```

So, all files that you see are located in root directory `public_html`

When I run script I get error:

`Fatal error: Class 'public_html\Helper\Pdo\FacadeQuery' not found in /home/bulud/public_html/parse.php on line 34`

Comment: Do you use an autoloader or do you include the files by yourself?

Comment: `use` does not load the files: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php